# Передача видео с веб-камеры на сайт

Tags: flash, web-camera, видео, linux

Всем доброго дня.

Пробую орагнизвать передачу видео (rtmp-поток) с веб-камеры на сайт.
Поставил на Linux erlyvideo и прописал в конфиге нужные настройки (секция rewrite).
Вывел на сайте флеш, который будет показыать rtmp-поток с erlyvideo (пример взят с документации).

Теперь осталось передать на сайт сам rtmp-поток с камеры.
Хотелось бы, чтобы захват осуществлялся не сторонним ПО, а флешем, но с флеш программированием не сталкивался.

Есть ли у кого готовый Flash элемент, который может захватывать видео с web-камеры и передавть rtmp-поток на указанный адрес (где стоит erlyvideo)?
Или подскажите, где есть код для такого флеша, который - только откомпилить и флешка готова?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Код взят из примеров к Red5 сервер.

Адаптирован к проекту на Flash Builder.

(Создать новый проект File->New->ActionScript Project)

[Ссылка](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder4-7/) на Flash Builder.

[Исходный проект](http://flightschool.acylt.com/devnotes/red5-video-chat-example/).

Самый простой случай, сильно упрощен для удобства понимания.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.media.Camera;
    import flash.media.Microphone;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;

public class test extends Sprite
{
    private var nc:NetConnection;

    public function test()
    {
         nc = new NetConnection;
         nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/server", "testName");
         nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, handler);
    }

    private function handler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        var netOut:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

        netOut.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
        netOut.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());

        netOut.publish("test");
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка при компиляции вашего кода в строке:

var netOut:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

может подскажите что не так?

Comment: сори, набарогозил, нужно объявить эту переменную в теле класса

    private var nc:NetConnection;

    public function test()

    {

         nc = new NetConnection;